# How to force WebLogic 10.3.2.0 to use TLS v1.0 minimum?

Tags: weblogic

Having trouble with chrome v 4x.xx and WebLogic not automatically handshaking via tls 1.0 minimum.  While calling a RESTful service from JavaScript front end I keep getting `net::ERR_SSL_FALLBACK_BEYOND_MINIMUM_VERSION` since Google have dropped support for SSL V3.0.  I have tried adding the flag forcing this to JAVA_OPTIONS and on another occasion to the starting arguments for WebLogic, despite knowing these only become suported in 10.3.6.  Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out WebLogic 10.3.2.0 has a bug in it.  When the client makes contact with the server for the first time it tells the server which SSL/TLS certificate version it supports - UP TO.  The latest Chrome I believe supports TLS v1.2, so this is the only information sent to WebLogic.  WebLogic has problems recognising that 1.2 is greater than 1.0, (which is the highest version available on WebLogic 10.3.2.0 (AFAIK, it is on ours) and should therefore be trusted, so terminates the connection.

source - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/iwX2PbNGk8E